# REST query 'getbytitle' gives an error message in IE

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I am trying to access tasks list using REST call using

**site_url/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(‘tasks')** in Internet Explorer.

It displays the message **"The webpage cannot be found".**

However i could get the results for **site_url/_api/web/** and **site_url/_api/web/lists**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is exactly the URL you used in IE, there's a typo with the first apostroph sign: **‘** instead of a plain **'**.

Comment: Great Thanks!! I missed to check that. I was trying to change the list names but dint concentrate on that.

Comment: Please, don't hesitate to mark as answered! :)